# Elementor loop grid with multiple custom post types

Tags: loops, grid, custom-post-type, elementor

I have created multiple Custom Post Types using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, and I have created a Loop Grid template. It lists each of my post types separately in the Source dropdown, but is there a way to get the Loop Grid to pull posts from each of my custom post types and not just one?

[Elementor Source dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY7kE.png)

Nothing has been attempted yet and I was hoping there would be a clear solution for this but when searching elsewhere I haven't found too much related to this. I am wondering if I need some other plugin to accomplish this.